# Matlab Matrixes in C++

Tags: c++

I'm a newbie programmer trying to translate MATLAB code into C++ for embedded systems. My question is: Can I write in a more elegant way these particular matrixes in order to multiply them afterwards? Should I use vectors instead? (I'm not very familiar with their syntax).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std; 

int main() {

    double matrixF [10][6] = {0.0};
    double freq {0.01};
    for(size_t i{0};i<10;++i){
            for(size_t j{0}; j<6;j++){
                if(j == 0) 
                    matrixF[i][j] = cos(2*M_PI*freq*i);  
                else if(j == 1) 
                    matrixF[i][j] = sin(2*M_PI*freq*i);
                else if(j == 2) 
                    matrixF[i][j] = cos(4*M_PI*freq*i);
                else if(j == 3) 
                   matrixF[i][j] = sin(4*M_PI*freq*i); 
                else if(j == 4) 
                   matrixF[i][j] = cos(6*M_PI*freq*i); 
                else if(j == 5)
                   matrixF[i][j] = sin(6*M_PI*freq*i); 
                }
    }      

    cout << "Displaying the matrix: " << endl;
    for (size_t i{0}; i<10;++i){
        for (size_t j{0}; j<6; ++j) {
            cout << matrixF[i][j] << " ";
        }
            cout << endl;
    }


    double matrixT [6][10] = {0.0};
        for (size_t i{0}; i<6; i++){
            for(size_t j{0}; j<10; j++){
                 if(i == 0) 
                    matrixT[i][j] = cos(2*M_PI*freq*j);  
                else if(i == 1) 
                    matrixT[i][j] = sin(2*M_PI*freq*j);
                else if(i == 2) 
                    matrixT[i][j] = cos(4*M_PI*freq*j);
                else if(i == 3) 
                   matrixT[i][j] = sin(4*M_PI*freq*j); 
                else if(i == 4) 
                   matrixT[i][j] = cos(6*M_PI*freq*j); 
                else if(i == 5)
                   matrixT[i][j] = sin(6*M_PI*freq*j); 
                }
    }

    cout << "Displaying the transpose Matrix: " << endl;
    for (size_t i{0}; i<6;++i){
        for (size_t j{0}; j<10; ++j) {
            cout << matrixT[i][j] << " ";
        }
            cout << endl;
    }
```

Help is appreciated.

Comment: What do you think about using [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/GettingStarted.html)?

Comment: Why the loops over `j`? [Cargo-cult programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming)? That is a very bizarre setup. If you don't see why, do a code walkthrough. Then manually unroll the loop and do another walkthrough. *(To unroll this loop: replace the `for` line with an initialization for `j`, then repeat the body of the loop 6 or 10 times, incrementing `j` between the copies.)* How much dead code is there in the unrolled version?

Comment: As for "more elegant", the right tool for the job depends on the job, and there is not much context to go on here. Are these constant matrices? Their value will never change and could be fixed at compiler time?